# Phase difference between SHM of different frequencies

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Can a phase difference be calculated for 2 SHM with
$$\phi_1=2wt+2rad$$
$$\phi_2=wt+2rad$$
So what is their phase difference is it $0$ rad,wt or does it simply not exist.
I need a proper answer from these 3 for an examination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly the angles $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are the *phases*. The 2 rad is the *phase constant*.

The phase difference, then, is $2\omega t + 2\ \text{rad}-(\omega t + 2\ \text{rad})=\omega t$.

So the phase difference, like the phases of the individual oscillations, keeps changing.

I hope this is a "proper answer".

Comment: Thanks Philip,well my book gives the wrong answer,it just subtracts the phase constants

Comment: I hesitate to condemn your book, but I do think it's wrong here. [In any case there's arguably little point in subtracting one phase constant from the other in this case, as the difference between the oscillations is dominated by the frequency difference.] Who wrote the book, I wonder. It would be nice to get support for the answer, but I don't think the topic will interest enough people to get many views.

Comment: this isn't really a book,but it was asked in some very old and prestigious national level examination,and the choices were all different.

Comment: https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer-physics/two-simple-harmonic-motion-are-represented-by-equations-y1-01-sin-100pi-t-pi-3-and-y2-01-cos-pi-t-th-11750094

Comment: The above is the link.i think the question must have involved the phase difference at t=0 but the statement has been omitted in my question booklet

Comment: I had a look at the doubt nut (like the name!) link. (a) They are comparing phase angles, not phases. (b) I wouldn't have bothered with the differentiation because the velocity sinusoid is $\pi/2$ ahead of the displacement sinusoid for both oscillations, so you you'll get the same phase constant difference for the displacements as for the velocities.